# undefined reference to `saving::rate'

Tags: c++

I am write this code but when i compile this code with g++ in arch linux i recive this error

> ```
>   /tmp/ccG7axw1.o: In function `saving::calculate()':
>   saving.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `saving::rate'
>   /tmp/ccG7axw1.o: In function `saving::modify()':
>   saving.cpp:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `saving::rate'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

saving.h

```
class saving{
private :
    double savebal;
public :
    saving(double newSavebal); 
    double calculate();
    void modify();
    static double rate;
};
```

saving.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"saving.h"
using namespace std;
saving :: saving(double newSavebal){
   savebal = newSavebal;
}
double saving :: calculate(){
    savebal += (savebal * (rate / 100))/12;
}

void saving :: modify(){
    cout<<"Please enter the new rate"<<endl;
    cin>>rate;
}
```

mainSaving.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"saving.h"
using namespace std;
void menu(saving );
int main(){
      saving s1(500);
      menu(s1);
}

  void menu(saving s){
    int m;
    cout<<"1) calculate month interest\n";
    cout<<"2) change rate of interest\n";
    cin>>m;
    switch(m){
        case 1 :
         s.calculate();
         break;
        case 2 :
         s.modify();
         break;

    }
}
```

Comment: @Jonas He's not trying to initialize it, he's trying to update it in a method.

Comment: first i am  declare the rate without static but it wasn't work

Answer (score 0):

In `Saving.h`, you declared the static variable:

```
static double rate;
```

But you still need to *define it* (in other words instantiate it). To do so you should add this to `Saving.cpp`:

```
 double saving::rate = 0;
```

Without that, the linker cannot find the actual variable, so any reference to it will result in a linker error.

Answer (score 0):

Because saving is a static member, you have to have it initialized beforehand.

In your `saving.cpp` file, add this line after including all the headers:

`double saving::rate = 0`

```
Your code should then like this:
#include<iostream>
#include"saving.h"
using namespace std;

double saving::rate = 0; //With this line here

saving :: saving(double newSavebal){
   savebal = newSavebal;
}
```

Comment: yes it worked 
tnx